# minmum number of subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, ... , n\}$, each of cardinality $r$, required such that their intersection is $\{1, 2, 3, ... , m\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $M = \{1, 2, 3, ... , m\}$ and   $N = \{1, 2, 3, ... , n\}$ be sets with $m < n$. Let $r \in \{1, ... , n\}$, with $m < r$.

> What is the minmum number of subsets of $N$, each of cardinality $r$, required such that their intersection is $M$?

---

I can see that at most $n - m \choose r - m $ sets are required since

$$N = \bigcap_{\sigma \in S_{n-m}} \{1, ... m, n + \sigma(1), ..., n + \sigma(r-n)\}$$

But I cannot improve upon it.

---

For those interested this question arose when thinking about this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757455/intersection-of-subspaces-by-construction).

Comment: The subsets must all contain $M$ so actually you are looking for sets contained in $N-M$ with empty intersection. Start with focusing on $M=\varnothing$ I would say.

Comment: If $2r \le n+m$ then you only need two

Comment: You need to exclude $n-m$ of the elements in $N$. Each subset gives you a chance to exclude $n-r$ of them; and you can choose _which_ $n-r$ elements freely. If $r=n$, you're out of luck, though.

Comment: Take two easy special cases. If $r=n$ the task is impossible. If $r=n-1$, then each subset must include $M$ and $r-m$ other elements chosen from the $r-m+1$ elements $m+1,\dots,n$, so we need $n-m$ subsets. So your formula does not look correct.

Comment: @almagest Indeed the formula should be $n-m \ choose r - m$. I will update my question to reflect this, I ought to have said $r<n$ too.  Thank you for the observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First have a look at my comment on your question. In this answer I focus on special case $M=\varnothing$.

Find the minimal number of subsets of $\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} $
with cardinality $r$ such that there intersection is empty.

Thinking of their complements this can be rephrased as:

Find the minimal number of subsets of $\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} $
with cardinality $n-r$ such that there union is $\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} $.

If $k$ denotes this number then $k$ is the smallest integer with $k(n-r)\geq n$.

Applying this on the general case where $M=\{1,\dots,m\}$ we must take $n-m$ instead of $n$ and $r-m$ instead of $r$. So $k$ is the smallest integer with $k(n-r)\geq n-m$.